# Inserting birthdate into mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I inserted the following into mongodb

```
db.friends.insert({name: "John Doe", birthday: 12/26/2013})
```

Then I extracted and gotten this result

```
{
    "name" : "John Doe",
    "birthdate" : 0.00022927891780350797
}
```

What is 0.00022927891780350797 ?

How can i get back my 12/26/2013, apart from storing it as a String ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is division.

```
12 / 26 / 2013 = 0.00022927891
```

Or twelve divided by twenty-six divided by two-thousand-thirteen

Consider using quotes around your `birthday` data.

Comment: Thanks shanabus! so it's division all the way and not some time representation like excel.

Answer (score 1):

to insert a date :

```
db.friends.insert({name: "John Doe", birthday: new Date('Dec 26,2013')})
```

[official mongodb documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/)

Answer (score 1):

Insert dates like this

```
db.friends.insert({name: "John Doe", birthday: new Date("Dec 26, 2013")})
```

and date time like this

```
db.friends.insert({name: "John Doe", birthday: new ISODate("2013-12-26T04:00:00Z")})
```

see the [mongodb docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/)

Comment: Thanks Diver! I like the ISODate - i didn't catch that when going thru  the docs. Thanks again!